# What is the error of preg_match in Xpath? Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, xpath, preg-match

I tried to grab the id from Property ID : with the code below:

```
<?php
$getURL = file_get_contents('http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-rent-in-phnom-penh-daun-penh-phsar-chas-2-beds-apartment-1001192296/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($getURL);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

/*echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//p[contains(text(),'Property ID:')][1], 'Property ID:'), '–'))");*/

$id = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"property-table")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
preg_match("/Property ID :(.*)/", $id, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

But it doesn't work;

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in W:\Xampp\htdocs\X\index.php on line 12
```

What is wrong? if I create sting like this

```
$id ="Property Details Property Type : Apartment Price $ 350 pm Building Size 72 Sqms Property ID : 1001192296";
```

And replace in my code it work. So what is the difference between data that created by myselt and grab from xpath?
Thank in advance for help me.

Comment: `$matches[1]` is not defined

Comment: Yes. but if I create a string with that data it work

Comment: Why it doesn't work with the data which get from xpath?

Comment: if your preg_match is not matching something, your array `$matches` has no index `1` the notice comes from `echo $matches[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `preg_match()` does not work because the `nodeValue` from the xpath you are getting is exactly this:

```
Property Details

                            Property Type : 
                         Apartment 


                    Price
                    $ 350 pm


                Building Size
                72 Sqms


                Property ID 
                 : 
                1001192296
```

So you have to try it like this:

```
$getURL = file_get_contents('http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-rent-in-phnom-penh-daun-penh-phsar-chas-2-beds-apartment-1001192296/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($getURL);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

/*echo $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(//p[contains(text(),'Property ID:')][1], 'Property ID:'), '–'))");*/

$id = $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@class,"property-table")]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$id = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $id);

preg_match("/Property ID :(.*)/", $id, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

This ( `$id = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $id);` ) will combine all tabs, whitespaces between the words to one whitespace.

**Update:**
Due to the comment below, I now get the full text of the HTML with `$xpath->evaluate()` and try to match all property ids ( like only digit and P-digits ).

```
$getURL = file_get_contents('http://realestate.com.kh/residential-for-rent-in-phnom-penh-daun-penh-phsar-chas-2-beds-apartment-1001192296/');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($getURL);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// this only returns the text of the whole page without html tags
$id = $xpath->evaluate( "//html" )->item(0)->nodeValue;
$id = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $id);

// not a good regex, but matches the property IDs
preg_match_all("/Property ID( |):[ |]((\w{0,1}[-]|)\d*)/", $id, $matches);

// after the changes you have to go for the matches is $matches[2]
foreach( $matches[2] as $property_id ) {
    echo $property_id."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I use this preg_match("/Property ID :(.*?)(?=\s)/", $id , $matches); it didn't work but, when I tested it in https://regex101.com/r/iF3rL5/1 it worked. I wonder what is the error when replace this in my code.

Comment: the problem is, what you test is never what you get the id you try to match isn't in the var `$id`, because you did filter just this div `//div[contains(@class,"property-table")]`, I'll update my answer, where i get the full html and match all property id's

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if `preg_match()` actually found anything.

If there are no results, there will be no `$matches[1]`. You should use `if(count($matches)>1) {... }` to go around the problem that you are having.

Comment: is there any way to solve this? what should I use to grab data instead of using Xpath.

Comment: The error is with the `preg_match()` and not xpath. Obviously, you're not parsing your HTML correctly, you'll need to recheck your xpath's expression.

Comment: but with this xpath's expression I get data as I want

Comment: I'll upvote this just because you are correct due to the error